# inserting data in a mysql database via python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert variables as data into a database
I'm using this (part of it)

```
query = "INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES (%S)"
aa="naam"
cursor.execute(query,aa)
```

and everytime, I get the following error message:
*"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%S)' at line 1"*

no matter what I try to do, I'm getting this message (put it in """, put () around it, ...)

Hope someone can help me

Comment: looks like you are using string formating "%s" (I think that needs to be lowercase s) but are not filling in the value

Comment: Aaaaaaargh ...So stupid of me! Been looking and searching on it for hours. Now, the next error arises:"Incorrect number of arguments executing prepared statement"

Comment: You likely need to use "?" for the placeholder rather than %s if you are using the standard sqllite3 module in python. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: solved-> aa=("naam",)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format needs to be lowercase, so change the query into: `query = "INSERT INTO table_name (name) VALUES (%s)"`.